# How to display a fetch result in a react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I have a "Banner" object that I want to use to display my text and I made a button to toggle whether the message shows or is hidden:

```js
function App() {
  function Banner(props) {
    if (!props.warn) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <div className="message">
        {this.state.message}
      </div>
    );
  }

  class Page extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {showMessage: false, message: 'foo'};
      this.handleToggleClick = this.handleToggleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleToggleClick() {
      this.setState(state => ({
        showMessage: !state.showMessage
      }));
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(
"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((json) => {
                this.setState({
                    message: json,
                    DataisLoaded: true
                });
            })

    }



    render() {
      return (
        <div class="App">
          <Banner warn={this.state.showMessage} />
          <button onClick={this.handleToggleClick}>
            {this.state.showMessage ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }



  return (
      <div className="App">
        <Page />
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Why is the text of the `message` variable not the text in the banner? If I replace the `{this.state.message}` with a string literal the banner displays it, but as the code is now when I press the button the page clears. Any ideas?

Comment: That's mean `fetch(
"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")` doesn't work yet. Try to console.log the response

Comment: `Banner` component doesn't have state, and also it's a functional component you can not use `this.state` in functional components. `message` state is in the `Page` component, you can send it to `Banner` as prop, like `warn` prop that you did.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass data to Banner and with `useEffect` and `useState` get and update the data when it changes

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Banner(props) {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    setMessage(props.message);
  }, [props]);
  if (!props.warn) {
    return null;
  }

  return <div className="message">{JSON.stringify(message)}</div>;
}
class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showMessage: false,
      message: 'foo',
    };
    this.handleToggleClick = this.handleToggleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleToggleClick() {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      showMessage: !state.showMessage,
    }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        this.setState({
          message: json,
          DataisLoaded: true,
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="App">
        <Banner message={this.state.message} warn={this.state.showMessage} />
        <button onClick={this.handleToggleClick}>
          {' '}
          {this.state.showMessage ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Page />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```